# How does one change nagios default url to custom url?

Tags: nagios

I am running Nagios Core 4.0.8 in my environment and I am looking to find a way to change the default url from https://example.com/nagios to https://example.com. Is there a way one can do that?

Answer (score 8):

You will need to edit the cgi.cfg file for Nagios.

1. `vim /usr/local/nagios/etc/cgi.cfg`

   Change `url_html_path=/nagios` to `url_html_path=/`
2. Edit nagios.conf:

   Change `ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagios/sbin"` to
   `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagios/sbin"`

   Comment out the line `Alias /nagios "/usr/local/nagios/share"` and then add below

   `DocumentRoot /usr/local/nagios/share`

   Add the following at top of the configuration:

   `<VirtualHost *:80>`
   `ServerName status.example.com`

   and add `</VirtualHost>` at the bottom.
3. Edit your `/usr/local/nagios/share/config.inc.php` file:

   Change `$cfg['cgi_base_url']='/nagios/cgi-bin';` to `$cfg['cgi_base_url']='/cgi-bin';`
4. Restart Apache and Nagios

Comment: This is a robust answer.

Comment: Thanks, great answer.

The **step 3** was __not necessary__ in my case because I let this 2 lines in my Apache VirtualHost :

`ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/nagios4 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios4` and `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin /usr/lib/cgi-bin/nagios4`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Apache to serve your Nagios page you can do different things. Apache configuration files are usually located in /etc/apache2/.

Probably your DocumentRoot is set to /var/www, so you can create a file named "index.html" and place this code inside it to redirect to /nagios URL:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=/nagios">
```

You can also edit your nagios apache config (probably /etc/nagios/apache2.conf...) or apache config /etc/apache2/*.conf and add:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /nagios
```

If you don't like these methods there are more, just think of it as using Apache to redirect, not like a Nagios thing.

Comment: awesome thanks for the great tip! the redirect worked